# Extract user view from a forum

Tags: html, extract, jsoup, forum

I want to extract a user post from a forum thread.Only the user text. how to extract from a html page using Jsoup or boilerplate? Please give me a solution.

Give me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Connect to website with jsoup like posted here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url
2. Use a selector to for getting the post you need. Examples and a list of all possible selectors are available here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

In general you should take a look into the [Jsoup Codebook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/).

Do you need to login or is it possible to visit the forum as guest?

Comment: Not login. I have to extract only the user views from the forum using Jsoup in java program

Comment: Then you can get the full HTML document like this: `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://yoururl.com/").get();`

Comment: Btw. you can use this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005872/extract-the-thread-head-and-thread-reply-from-a-forum/13014174#comment17678171_13014174